# Styling a jQuery UI Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

can anyone tell me how to get css like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#mouseover for the below code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<title>jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu Plugin v 2.6</title>
<link href="css/dcaccordion.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.cookie.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){


                        $('.accordion-6').dcAccordion({
                        eventType: 'hover',
                        autoClose: true,
                        saveState: true,
                        disableLink: true,
                        menuClose: false,
                        speed: 'medium',
                        showCount: true,

                        autoExpand: true,
                        cookie  : 'dcjq-accordion-1',
                        classExpand  : 'dcjq-current-parent',

                        menuClose: false    
                    });

});
</script>
<link href="css/skins/blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/skins/graphite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/skins/grey.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="graphite demo-container">

            <ul class="accordion accordion-6">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a>
                    <ul class="accordion"  id="accordion-6">
                        <li><a href="#">Mobile Phones &#038; Accessories</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Desktop</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
                <ul class="accordion"  id="accordion-6">
                    <li><a href="#">About Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Page 2</a></li>            
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Iam new to this CSS, so please can anyone tell me how to achive that..?

Iam thinking to have my CSS like this site:

```
http://bag-saver.com/uk/shop/black-handbags/
```

Can anyone pls..?

Comment: Download the theme and add that theme css to your html page ..

Comment: First of all, don't reuse your id ("accordion") as a class - that can lead to all sorts of problems. Second, do you have a live example of your code? Third, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: OK I will change that ID name.. AT first Iam not good at CSS, and the Above code is not related to any JQuery theme.. It was bit customized, so I cant directly use that JQuery theme CSS.. So, for the above code, i need a  customized css..  Iam thinking to have my css like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#mouseover  (If not exactly, atleast similar to that..), so can anyone here pls... ?

Comment: The css that is used in the examples is the default theme that comes packaged with jQuery UI. Include this in your site, and you can override the theme with another stylesheet afterwards. We can't write your CSS for you because we don't know what your design looks like! If you're really just starting out with CSS then Google is your friend :)
(https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?&q=learning+css#hl=en&output=search&q=learning+css&oq=learning+css)

Comment: Actually I already downloaded jquery ui and tried like that, BUT didnt understood how to change CSS as per my requirmement..

All I need  is a CSS to get like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#mouseover

Comment: The chief difference that I can see is that the demo is using divs and h3s, and you're using list items. You could change your markup to be the same as the demo's and the theme would work, but beyond that until you get an example up and running somewhere that we can see we won't be able to help any further.

Comment: HI,

Iam thinking to have my output like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#mouseover 

Can u tell me what to write css to make my accordion look like that link?

Comment: In short? No, not unless you put something online for us to look at.

Comment: Iam thinking to have CSS like this site: http://bag-saver.com/uk/shop/black-handbags/  (just mouseover on its categories)

Comment: Having the accordian work onmouseover is all in the documentaion and examples: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#mouseover  There is plenty of CSS available direct from the jQuery UI site and anything you don't understand can be googled.  It's not really possible to tell you what to do here...

Comment: Hmm its not a good advice but still if you want exactly same CSS then use some developer tool like firebug..

Comment: Iam just learning CSS now, it takes me time to get understand and get an answer for it myself.. Iam not asking exactly like this, atleast similar look is enuf for me.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a complete ready to go package...http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxAccordion/index.shtml...just download...follow the steps and you are good to go.

This is a simple inline css to start with...Its uses google accordian API...

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">        </script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#accordion").accordion({ active: false,
    collapsible: true
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="accordion">
<h3>
<a href="#" style="background-color: Blue; height: 25px; color: White; text-decoration: none;">
    Start Service</a></h3>
<div style="height: 40px;">
<span>Start or Stop Servcice </span>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
    <p>
        some text
    </p>
</asp:Panel>
</div>
<h3>
<a href="#" style="background-color: Blue; height: 25px; color: White; text-decoration: none;">
    Customer Service</a></h3>
<div>
<b>Contact Us</b>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSrvc" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
    <p>some text<p>
</asp:Panel>
</div>
<h3>
<a href="#" style="background-color: Blue; height: 25px; color: White; text-decoration: none;">
   some text</a></h3>
<div style="height: 40px;">
<span>some text </span>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
    <p>
        some text
    </p>
</asp:Panel>


</div>
 <h3>
some text
</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it uses the same Html and CSS structure as you want

Comment: I downloaded it, OMG, it has so many files in it, it takes a lot of time to udnestand it, But unfortunately i dnt have much time.. why dont you pls just send me css for my above problem..? pls.. Does my query is that tough?

Comment: I cannot just create an css for you without knowing your existing code base & what data you want to put in the accordion... The best I can do is point you to the easiest plugin...<http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu-plugin/download/> just delete every thing from the body except for div class="blue demo-container" ... this div is the accordion you can modify as you like.. don't  have to worry about the JQuery files just use them as they are...sorry if I wasn't useful...

Comment: Hello Scorpio, Your link: http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu-plugin/download/%3E working like a charm.. BUT I have a little problem, actually my code dynamically geenrates ul, li and anchor tags, so in this case, its not showing any arrow symbol for other menus and with that iam unable to even either hover or click it... Why dont you please try once for dynamic content if possible..?

Comment: BTW, I just updated my code above with the help of the link you given to me.. Really unable to work your code for dynamic content...

Comment: is it working now? if not then update your latest code, let me see if I can do anything...